# How to make div behave like overflow:hidden and overflow:visible

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="select2-container select2-container-multi" id="s2id_5268118036b78">
    <ul class="select2-choices">
        <li class="select2-search-choice">
            <div>aaaaa aaaaaaa</div>
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a></li>
        <li class="select2-search-choice">
            <div>bbbb bbbbbbbbb</div>
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a></li>
        <li class="select2-search-choice">
            <div>ccc ccc ccccccccc</div>
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a></li>
        <li class="select2-search-field"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitilize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen4" style="width: 10px;">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="select2-drop select2-drop-multi select2-display-none select2-drop-active">
        <ul class="select2-results">
            <li class="select2-no-results">No matches found</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
.select2-container-multi {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 250px;

   .select2-choices {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
```

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/mnbayazit/pen/boJKC)

As you can see, the little gray boxes ("bbb" and "ccc") float outside of their container when `overflow: visible` is set. If I change that to `overflow: hidden`, then their container expands to fit them.

I *want* the container to expand to fit them, *but* I'm also applying some JavaScript to them to make them draggable, so they can be pulled outside of the box. If `overflow: hidden` is set, then their clipped to the box and you won't be able to see them once you drag them out. Which is why I was trying `overflow: visible`.

Thus I need to behaviours of both. Is there some CSS I can apply to make the box expand to fit its children, but also have `overflow: visible`?

Note that `overflow: auto` just creates scrollbars, which is no good either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried giving it a float?

```
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices {
overflow: visible;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: That actually looks like it works! It was because the `li`s are floated...not because of some weird visibility. Didn't realize this was a clearfix problem. Thanks!